# Trouble finding $\mathbb{E}(T^\alpha)$ of a simple random walk. T is the first time the walk is at the origin.

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

Let $(S_n, n\geq0$) be a simple random walk with $S_0=0$ and define $T:=inf\{n\geq 1 : S_n=0\}$. In class we proved that $$\mathbb{P}(T=2n)=\dfrac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n}.$$
The professor then said that using this and Stirling Approximation($n!\sim n^n(\sqrt{2\pi n})e^{-n}$) one can prove that 
$$\mathbb{E}(T^\alpha)<\infty \Leftrightarrow \alpha < 1/2 $$

I'm having some trouble with this. This is what I've done:

\begin{align} \mathbb{E}(T^\alpha) & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^\alpha\mathbb{P}(T=k) \\ & = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(2n)^\alpha \dfrac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}2^{-2n} \\&\sim2^\alpha\sqrt{\pi}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^{\alpha-1/2}}{2n-1} \text  {  (Using Stirlings Approximation) } \end{align}

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: You are almost finished. The common term can be written as $\frac{1}{n^{3/2-\alpha}} \times \frac{n}{2n-1} \le  \frac{1}{n^{3/2-\alpha}} $  for all $n \ge 1$.

Comment: It is well-known that $\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$ so $P(T=2n)$ decays like $n^{-3/2}$.